# Convert List<Object[]> to list<String> Cast exception

Tags: java, java-stream, classcastexception

I have a list with an array of objects (strings) :

```
 List<Object[]> params  = ...
```

I want to cast this list to a list of strings List

```
  List<Object> results = params.stream()
                            .flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then I want to do something like that :

```
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I get this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.lang.String and [Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

This how I create the params :

```
 Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
 List<Object[]> params = query.getResultList();;
```

Comment: Where do you get that exception?

Comment: In this part List<Object> results = params.stream() ...

Comment: @e2rabi can you please show how did you create `params`?

Comment: which java version you are using?

Comment: I'm using java 11 @BuildSlayer I updated my question

Comment: I found the issue with debug mode the parms contains a list of object and not a list of array of objects ,thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Stream the arrays
- flatten the arrays into a stream of objects.
- filter out non strings.
- cast via a map remaining objects to strings
- collect into a List

```
List<Object> params = List.of(1, 2,
                   "hello",
                   "computer",  new Object(), 4.32,
                   new Object[]{1,2});

List<String> strings = params.stream()
        .filter(ob -> ob instanceof String)
        .map(ob -> (String) ob)
        .collect(Collectors.toList(), "java");

System.out.println(strings);
```

Prints

```
[hello, computer, java]
```

Comment: this give me the same exception in the collector part  ...... at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)

Comment: I found the issue with debug mode the parms contains a list of object and not a list of array of objects ,thank you

Comment: @e2rabi That would make a difference.  I modified my answer to comply with the changes.